# How can I make 5 copies of one file easily?

Tags: bash

I can move 5 files to somewhere using:

```
$ mv my-{1..5}.jpg /path/to/dir/
```

How can I make copy of one file by 5 times easily

```
# doesn't work
$ cp my.jpg my-{1..5}.jpg
```

Is it possible not to use a `for loop`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
for f in {1..5}; do cp my.jpg my$f.jpg; done
```

(don't have bash here to try it myself)

Comment: replace `for f in $f` with `for f in $(seq 5)`.

Comment: Is it possible **not** to use a `for loop`?

Comment: @kev - I've always seen it done this way; also, more readabe.

Comment: @kev, what is wrong with a for loop? This is what for loops are for...

Comment: @kev, `mv` implements a loop/iterator with your example. This is the same thing, just different syntax.

Comment: @DanD.: `seq` isn't necessary in Bash. You can use `for f in {1..5}` or `for ((f=1; f<=5; f++))`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to do it without a `for` loop and without the risks of using `eval`:

```
printf '%s\n' {1..5} | xargs -I {} cp my.jpg my-{}.jpg
```

It's still effectively a loop.

Answer (score 5):

Try `tee`:

```
tee <my.jpg >/dev/null my-{1..5}.jpg
```

Or `parallel`:

```
parallel cp my.jpg ::: my-{1..5}.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without a loop..  using `tee` and `{}` brace expansion.

*EDIT:* (ammended as per *Dennis Williamson's* comment:

For a file named "my-.jpg"

```
pre="my-"; suf=".jpg"
<"$pre$suf" tee "$pre"{1..5}"$suf" >/dev/null
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use eval. `<"$pre$suf" tee "$pre"{1..5}"$suf"` works just fine.